# Different padding-left on identically styled input and select element

Tags: html, css, padding

I am wondering, why a HTML select tag has a larger padding-left than a input tag, although both have the same style applied?

This is reproducible with Firefox 17, Chrome 23, IE 8 and IE 9. Only Opera shows both elements with an identical padding-left.

The same problem occurs while using a reset style sheet. Input and select have a margin and padding of 0 and no border, box-sizing: border-box is used.

Here is a screenshot of Firefox:

[image: Here is a screenshot of Firefox]
.

And a code example (there is no form action etc):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>input and select - padding-left</title>
    <style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    }

    input, select {
        width: 150px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: none;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }



    body {
        background-color: #007;
        font-size: 36px;
    }

    div {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 140px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            <input value="Hello input" /><br/>
            <select size="1">
                <option>Hello select</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Because Opera shows everything as desired, if I would assign different values for padding-left, it would look misaligned in Opera. Therefore, I hope there is another solution.

Comment: Browsers love to control the styling of form elements. If you want everything to be 100% consistent, you'll have to use mock-form elements, such as [jQuery Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

Comment: @ChristianVarga That's true, but the browser-specific rendering of form elements is okay for me. This problem seems a bit weird, because this is an inconsistency within one and the same browser.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't checked this, but you could try making the `line-height` in the `input` and `select` the same as the height (so 30px).

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but it did not have an effect on the padding. Thanks anyhow :)